# send param to function without executing untill clicked javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Function `current_child` will execute without html `li.first` is being clicked becouse of a param. How could i send a param like `event.target` to current_child when its clicked. At the moment it executes when page is being loaded. Skipping the param like `$(document).on("click", "li.first", current_child)` and the function will wait to be executed untill the html object is being clicked.

```
var toggle = false;
function current_child(value){
    if(value == 1){
        alert("Hello");
    }
    event.preventDefault();
}


$(document).on("click", "li.first", current_child(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `bind` instead of directly calling your handler:

```
$(document).on("click", "li.first", current_child.bind(null, 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use lexical scoping of Javascript variables and return inner function

```
function current_child(value){
    return function (event) {
        if(value == 1){
            alert("Hello");
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    };
}

$(document).on("click", "li.first", current_child(1));
```

its called [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 1):

You can also wrap it in an anonymous function:

```
$(document).on("click", "li.first", function() { current_child(1); });
```

Comment: I would rather avoid anonymous functions becouse it can become clumpsy if have to use it multiple times.